# DHCP does not crash/stop on duplicate MAC entries (Centos)

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

We have two DHCP servers running in our environment. Recently one of them crashed and we had to rebuild it luckily we had the backup of our `dhcpd.conf` file.

The new server was built on `Centos 6` while the old runs on `Centos 5`. The versions of DHCP installed is as follows:

> Centos 5

```
[root@dhcp2 dhcpd-config]# rpm -qa | grep dhcp
dhcpv6-client-1.0.10-20.el5
dhcp-3.0.5-33.el5_9
```

> Centos 6

```
[root@dhcp dhcp]# rpm -qa | grep dhcp
dhcp-4.1.1-53.P1.el6.centos.x86_64
dhcp-common-4.1.1-53.P1.el6.centos.x86_64
```

Whenever MAC duplication took place due to human error our `dhcpd` service would stop, indicating an error in the specific line.

The new DHCP Server that we installed on `Centos 6` does not exhibit this behavior and ignores if MAC duplication took place in the configuration file.

This functionality is important to us as we don't want any duplicate entries in our server.

Here is an example:

```
host HONT-1-1-user1 {
hardware ethernet 00:17:cc:1b:89:fe;
fixed-address 10.6.0.18;
}

host HONT-1-1-user2 {
hardware ethernet 00:17:cc:1e:03:c7;
fixed-address 10.6.0.22;
}
```

In previous cases if the MACs were the same the `dhcpd` service would stop but thats not happening in the newer Version.

Any help on enabling or enforcing such a check would be greatly appreciated.